# Build a Responsive CSS Ribbon

Tags: html, css

I'm building a component that will be used by others. I need to build a ribbon that needs to be responsive and adapt to the content of the ribbon.

I know how to do it using fixed sized borders, as shown in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw672.png).

But if I change the text inside the ribbon, I get something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpLcF.png).

Which css technique can I use to make this component?

**IMPORTANT**: I can't use JS. Only CSS3 and HTML.

Comment: This may be useful https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution, where the width of the ribbon will adapt to the width of the content:

```css
.ribbon {
float:left;
clear: left;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 40px;
margin:12px 0;
padding: 0 4px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-size: 10px;
font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px rgb(0,0,0);
}

.ribbon::before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
left: -24px;
z-index: -12;
width: 12px;
height: 16px;
border: 12px solid rgb(255,255,255);
border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-right-color: rgb(215,0,0);
}

.ribbon::after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: -14px;
z-index: 12;
width: 28px;
height: 28px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
transform: rotate(45deg);
box-shadow: inset 2px -1px 1px -1px rgb(0,0,0);
}

.ribbon span {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 6px;
width: 66%;
margin-top: 4px;
line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">
<span>Ribbon Example</span>
</div>

<div class="ribbon">
<span>Ribbon Example with lots more text</span>
</div>

<div class="ribbon">
<span>Ribbon Example with a very large amount of text to show what happens when the ribbon contains an entire sentence</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I can't force the background to be white. So I can't use a white square and rotate it. Remember that it is a component that I don't know where it will be used

Answer (score 0):

Play around with `line-height` on the text (or add it). Increase the `line-height` px amount.

It'd be nice to see a jsfiddle of this in action where I can help you.